# How to get the request URI in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, httprequest

I've got a simple Grails app with the following RESTful uri...

```
http://localhost:8080/kennis-api/funds/test/700
```

The mapping in my URIMappings is

```
 "/funds/test/$fcode" (controller: "fundCache"){
    action = [GET: "show"]
 }
```

In my controller, I need to extract the request URI, in this case "/funds/test/700", but invoking request.uri or request.getRequestUri does not work. I tried using request.requestURL, but that gives me

http://localhost:8080/kennis-api/grails/fundCache/show.dispatch

Is there a special member or function from which to get the request uri?

Comment: I got it, not intuitive, but whatever... 'request.forwardURI'

Comment: Just found this. Totally unintuitive. Grails must be doing some circus tricks under the hood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its Simple, You need the Original address, that is same as the one where your response will be forwarded, its simply stored in the Request, and can be retrieved by:
.

```
String originalURI = request.forwardURI  
//Do this where request is available, ex: Controllers :)
// Everywhere else you can use RequestContextHolder
```

.
.
Hope that helps
Regards
Kushal